# Extracting href with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href

I use this code to get acces to my link :

```
links = soup.find("span", { "class" : "hsmall" })
links.findNextSiblings('a')
for link in links:
  print link['href']
  print link.string
```

Link have no ID or class or whatever, it's just a classic link with a href attribute.

The response of my script is :

```
print link['href']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Can you help me to get href value ?
Thx !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, it works now with following code :

```
linkSpan = soup.find("span", { "class" : "hsmall" })
link = [tag.attrMap['href'] for tag in linkSpan.findAll('a', {'href': True})]
for lien in link:
  print "LINK = " + lien`
```

Answer (score 9):

Links is still referring to your soup.find. So you could do something like:

```
links = soup.find("span", { "class" : "hsmall" }).findNextSiblings('a')
for link in links:
    print link['href']
    print link.string
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I have tried with your code : i have no error this time but always no value too for href. I don't understand why. I will try another way i think..

Comment: @Koolen would you mind to post your new code to us? :) Also, if Chris answer solved your problem (at least to some degree) it would be nice from you to [mark it as the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thank you, @Chris Pickett ! For me this code works pretty fine!