# Best way to get 'hrefs' from CSS selector in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

Writing a script that would, initially, scrape the data for all of the census blocks in a given census block group.  In order to do that, though, I first need to be able to get a link all of the block groups in a given tract.  The tracts are defined by a list with the URLs to them, which returns a page which lists the block groups within the css selector "div#rList3 a". When I run this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

tracts = ['http://www.usa.com/NY023970800.html','http://www.usa.com/NY023970900.html',
       'http://www.usa.com/NY023970600.html','http://www.usa.com/NY023970700.html',
       'http://www.usa.com/NY023970500.html']

class Scrape:
    def scrapeTracts(self):
        for i in tracts:
            html = urlopen(i)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
            bgs = soup.select("div#rList3 a")
            print(bgs)

s = Scrape()
s.scrapeTracts()
```

This gives me an output that looks like: `[<a href="/NY0239708001.html">NY0239708001</a>]` (with the real amount of links cut out for the sake of the length of this post.)  My question is, how can I get *just* the string after 'href', in this case being `/NY0239708001.html`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting href with Beautiful Soup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183922/extracting-href-with-beautiful-soup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this mostly in one line, by doing this:

```
bgs = [i.attrs.get('href') for i in soup.select("div#rList3 a")]
```

Output:

```
['/NY0239708001.html']
['/NY0239709001.html', '/NY0239709002.html', '/NY0239709003.html', '/NY0239709004.html']
['/NY0239706001.html', '/NY0239706002.html', '/NY0239706003.html', '/NY0239706004.html']
['/NY0239707001.html', '/NY0239707002.html', '/NY0239707003.html', '/NY0239707004.html', '/NY0239707005.html']
['/NY0239705001.html', '/NY0239705002.html', '/NY0239705003.html', '/NY0239705004.html']
```

Answer (score 2):

Each node has an attrs dictionary which contains the attributes of that node...including CSS classes, or in this case, the href.

```
hrefs = []
for bg in bgs:
    hrefs.append(bg.attrs['href'])
```

Comment: You can make it simpler: `hrefs = [bg['href'] for bg in bgs]`.