# beautifulsoup get href out of unsorted list

Tags: beautifulsoup

why is this code not outputting three links to the three hits the search engine found?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib import urlopen

import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
url = "https://www.conrad.de/de/Search.html?search=mosfet+driver"
page = opener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
#print soup.prettify


result = soup.find_all('ul', class_="ccpProductList")

products  = result[0].find_all('a', class_="ccpProductListItem__title")

for product in products:
    print product.href
```

output is "None" three times.

Comment: similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183922/extracting-href-with-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 0):

I think your issues is the last line `print product.href`. I think you need `print product['href']` instead. The following code does what I think you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'https://www.conrad.de/de/Search.html?search=mosfet+driver'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
#print soup.prettify

result = soup.find_all('ul', class_="ccpProductList")
products = result[0].find_all('a', class_="ccpProductListItem__title")
for p in products:
    print p['href']
```